# Word list storage returning "string index out of range". Why?

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I am working on an assignment where we have to ask the user for a word, and then if the word has a letter that repeats the initial letter in the word, such as: ApplesAuce (the A repeats), the program will store the word in the list and then print out the list when the user is done entering words.

I am getting this error

> if word[0].lower() in word[1:].lower(): IndexError: string index out
>   of range

Here is my code:

```
wordlist = [] 
word = input("Please enter a hilariously long word: ")
# I said "hilariously long" to increase the likelihood of a repeat letter
while wordlist != '':
    word = input("Please enter another hilariously long word: ")
    if word[0].lower() in word[1:].lower():
        wordlist.append(word) 

word = input("Please enter another hilariously long word: ")

print("All of the words that had repeated first letters are: ")
print(wordlist)
```

Comment: What does `word` contain if you don't enter a word (i.e., to stop the loop)?

Comment: I suspect that you are entering no value i.e. blank and you are not testing for it.

Comment: You are probably overwriting your variables you are comparing. There is word which you initialize and also another input which you store in word.

Answer (score 0):

Test for the presence of a word and break out of the `while` loop if it isn't there.

```
wordlist = []
msg = "Please enter a hilariously long word: "
# I said "hilariously long" to increase the likelihood of a repeat letter
while True:
    word = input(msg)
    if word:
        if word[0].lower() in word[1:].lower():
            wordlist.append(word)
    else:
        break

print("All of the words that had repeated first letters are: ")
print(wordlist)
```

Note also that `wordlist` is a `list` so the test `while wordlist != ""` will always be the case because a `list` is not a `string`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.I have introduced the breaker that is quit or done will break the loop. I have also moved your first input inside which will add another if wordlist is populated.

```
wordlist = [] 
# I said "hilariously long" to increase the likelihood of a repeat letter
while 1:
    word = input("Please enter {}hilariously long word: ".format('another ' if wordlist else ''))

    # get out if done or quit is typed
    if word in ('done','quit'):
        break
    if word[0].lower() in word[1:].lower():
        wordlist.append(word) 

print("All of the words that had repeated first letters are: ")
print(wordlist)
```